HDMI output in hyprid GPU device
I have hybrid graphics setup (integrated Intel and dedicated nvidia). I use hyprland which runs on integrated graphics. Also, have installed nvidia drivers which works fine (i use them only for deep learning tasks). The problem is I couldn't use secondary monitor with hyprland running on integrated graphics. It looks like the HDMI is binded to nvidia drivers. It works only on the following scenario

Run hyprland on nvidia
Remove nvidia drivers
How to make HDMI output work with hyperland running on integrated graphics?

